# Cannot Set Root Password MySQL CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, linux, centos6

**Overview**

Hi! I'm new to Linux, but I was able to get MySQL installed and running on several VPS; however, I recently reset my VPS by reinstalling CentOS 6. I've run into a problem regarding MySQL where it won't let me log in or set a password. I've never run into this issue before, so I'm hoping for someone to see if they can help me out.

**Steps that replicated the issue**

```
yum install wget
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install mysql mysql-server
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
mysqladmin -u root -p "setpasswordhere"
```

At the last step it won't let me and tells me to input the current root password, but I was never prompted to set a password in the first case. I've reinstalled the VPS 2-3 times now and done the same procedure that didn't cause me the problems in the past. Albeit reinstalling the entire VPS isn't the greatest thing to do, but in times where I'm completely lost and new to something, reinstalling and starting from scratch only takes about 5-10 minutes.

**Research:**
I followed some steps for installing MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

The error message is:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Or

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

So obviously a password is set here, but I'm never prompted to create one in the first place.

Console Output:

```
[root@vps83299 ~]# mysqladmin -u root -p ""
Enter password:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
[root@vps83299 ~]#
```

Error when I get when following this instruction: https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/

```
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newpass") where User='root';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Use option 2. My answer bellow.

Comment: So you never used a root password for MySQL... well then, you might need to reset the root password:  https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/

Comment: Same thing @Douglas

Comment: Also did you run `mysql_secure_installation` per the link you specified in the "Research" section of your post. If so, did you specify a root password anywhere in the `mysql_secure_installation` script?

Comment: @edhurtig This is what i get when I get to resetting the password
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newpass") where User='root';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

Comment: It is possible that the password field has an uppercase `P` (named: `Password`)

Answer (score 0):

For acess mysql, use:

```
mysqladmin -uroot -psetpasswordhere
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -psetpasswordhere
```

Comment: Show console output.

Comment: During installation, you set the password?

Comment: I suggest you uninstall and install again. Note that need to ask for the password during installation.

Comment: how do you get it to prompt you for a password? Mine just installs MySQL and that's it.

Comment: This is automatic process. It happens in installation.

Comment: When I do " yum install mysql mysql-server" it simply prompts if I want to install it, and I hit yes, and that's it. No password.

Comment: Then something went wrong. Why during installation that you provide the root password.

Comment: I honestly don't know. It never asks me though.

Comment: You might... somehow... have the a yum defaults set which is automatically setting the root password and skipping the prompt altogether.

Answer (score -1):

RECOVER MYSQL ROOT PASSWORD( for linux users)

#

Login to root user and run step1 and 2
Step 1# `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`
Step 2# `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
Output : Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
mysqld_safe[6025]: startedStep # 3: Connect to mysql server using mysql client:
Keep this running................

Step 3
Login to new terminal (with root user)

## `mysql -u root`

mysql> `use mysql;`
mysql> `update user set password=PASSWORD('NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD') where User='root';`
mysql> `flush privileges;`
mysql> `quit`

Step 4 # Stop MySQL Server:

## `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`

Step 5 # `/etc/init.d/mysql start`

## `mysql -u root -pNEWPASSWORD`

## --------------------- completed----------

Comment: Have you understand how to perform the steps mentioned above? Because this is the only way to recover the password.